# How to recognize MICR codes with Tessaract in Android

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I am trying to recognize MICR codes on cheques using [Tessaract library](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/tree/master/tess-two).

For this I have downloaded '[mcr.traineddata](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/tesseract-ocr/obWI4cz8rXg/9glPuTdRX5EJ)' and saved it in assests.
At runtime I have copied this file into sdcard (OCR_DATA_PATH) and initialised Tessaract OCR engine with

```
baseApi.init(OCR_DATA_PATH, 'mcr', TessBaseAPI.OEM_TESSARACT_ONLY);
```

But I am getting Fatal signal 11 error.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Does it work if you use the trained data file for English and use "eng"? If so, the MICR trained data file is likely not for Tesseract 3.02+ and you'll need to re-train.

Comment: Have you solved this Problem? I facing the same problem.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue.